# Extracting specific values from a pandas columns and storing it in new columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, split

I have a pandas column which is storing data in a form of a list in the following format:

```
text
[['Mark','PERSON'],['Data Scientist','TITLE'], ['Berlin','LOC'], ['Python','SKILLS'], ['Tableau,','SKILLS'], ['SQL','SKILLS'], ['AWS','SKILLS']]
[['John','PERSON'],['Data Engineer','TITLE'], ['London','LOC'], ['Python','SKILLS'], ['DB2,','SKILLS'], ['SQL','SKILLS']
[['Pearson','PERSON'],['Intern','TITLE'], ['Barcelona','LOC'], ['Python','SKILLS'], ['Excel,','SKILLS'], ['SQL','SKILLS']
[['Broody','PERSON'],['Manager','TITLE'], ['Barcelona','LOC'], ['Team Management','SKILLS'], ['Excel,','SKILLS'], ['Good Communications','SKILLS']
[['Rita','PERSON'],['Software Developer','TITLE'], ['London','LOC'], ['Dot Net','SKILLS'], ['SQl Server,','SKILLS'], ['VS Code,'SKILLS']
```

What I want to see as an output is :

```
PERSON    TITLE                 LOC         SKILLS       
Mark      Data Scientist        Berlin      Python, Tableau, SQL, AWS
John      Data Engineer         London      Python, DB2,SQL
```

..... and so on for the rest of the input rows as well

So essentially splitting the data by "," and storing the left part before "," as the column header and the right part of the "," as the value.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you have a data frame like this call it "**df**":

```
   index    text
0    1     [[Mark, PERSON], [Data Scientist, TITLE], [Ber...
1    2     [[John, PERSON], [Data Engineer, TITLE], [Lond...
2    3     [[Pearson, PERSON], [Intern, TITLE], [Barcelon...
3    4     [[Broody, PERSON], [Manager, TITLE], [Barcelon...
4    5     [[Rita, PERSON], [Software Developer, TITLE], ...
```

- You can try something like that :

```
person=[]
skills=[]
title=[]
loc=[]
temp=[]

for i in range(len(df['text'])):
    
    for j in range(len(df['text'][i])):
        
        if df['text'][i][j][1]=='PERSON':
            
            person.append(df['text'][i][j][0])
        
        elif df['text'][i][j][1]=='TITLE':
            
            title.append(df['text'][i][j][0])
        
        elif df['text'][i][j][1]=='LOC':
            
            loc.append(df['text'][i][j][0])
        
        elif df['text'][i][j][1]=='SKILLS':
            
            temp.append(df['text'][i][j][0].replace(",", ""))
    
    skills.append(",".join(temp))
    temp=[]
```

- Output

```
    PERSON  TITLE              LOC           SKILLS
0   Mark    Data Scientist    Berlin    Python,Tableau,SQL,AWS
1   John    Data Engineer     London    Python,DB2,SQL
2   Pearson Intern            Barcelona Python,Excel,SQL
3   Broody  Manager           Barcelona Team Management,Excel,Good Communications
4   Rita    Software Developer London   Dot Net,SQl Server,VS Code
```

Comment: The information is stored correctly in all the lists as per my requirement but just to be clear, if I run the above code for let's say 1000 rows of similar looking text, then by just assigning a list to a new data frame column will give me the desired output, correct? Like df['Skills] = skills ,df['location']= loc ?

Comment: Sure, but if you want can you show me a top 5 of your data frame in order to verify the procedure that you need?

Comment: Hey! I have updated my input. Maybe if you want to give it a try now? I have added five dummy rows there. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Django0602,  I've tried and can say that works, I hope was helpful for you,  good luck dude.